# Will the mail client elementary OS 6 include contact syncing?

Tags: pantheon-mail

I tried Beta 2 of elementary OS 6 and I admit to being very impressed.  If contact syncing is going to be added prior to release, you can count on me as a convert.  I'd love to move away from Thunderbird but so far, I have not seen an adequate replacement.

Comment: I believe the intent is to have contacts sync, but elementary does not publish timescales.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that contact syncing has *not* been written into the current, stable version of `pantheon-mail` for elementaryOS 6.0. I guess I'll be waiting for 7.0...